# Getting rid of overlapping double scroll bars

Tags: html, css

I am making a website that uses javascript, html, and css and on one of the pages I am displaying all of the users as li's in a ul. The UL is in a div that's in another div. Both of these divs are getting a scroll bar on the phone, when im on my computer, it's not a problem. I am trying to make this website responsive and mobile friendly, but the two scroll bars are making it hard to use on a phone.

I will post the code below and yes I know there are some css things that aren't being used, but try to ignore those. Also the ul with the id of "supervisee-list" is dynamically filled with all the users.

Here is the HTML for the page (I am using a lesser used view engine called handlebars):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/admin-managesupers.css">
<div id="background">
    {{> navbar}}
    <div id="employee-manage" class="hidden-div">
        <button id="back-btn"><span id="back-sign">&lt;</span> Back</button>
        <h1 id="employee-name">Carsdan Dvorachek</h1>
        <h2 id="supervisor-title">Supervisor Status</h2>
        <select name="supervisor-status" id="supervisor-status-select"></select>
        <h2 id="supervisor-title">Supervising</h2>
        <ul id="supervisee-list">
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="../js/admin-managesupers.js"></script>
```

Here is the css for the page:

```
#background {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: gainsboro;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.hidden-div {
    display: none;
}

#employee-manage, #employee-select {
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 600px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px grey;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#select-employee-title {
    padding-top: 20px;
}

li {
    border: 1px solid;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    max-width: 80%;
}

li:hover {
    background-color: gainsboro;
}

.mark-super {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    text-align: right;
}

#back-btn {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    background: none;
    border: solid 2.5px rgb(9, 139, 175);
    margin: 20px;
    color: rgb(9, 139, 175);
    font-size: 100%;
    padding: 5px;;
}

#back-sign {
    font-size: 110%;
}

#employee-name {
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.supervisee, .supervisee > span {
    color: green;
}

.othersupervisee, .othersupervisee > span {
    color: grey;
    border-color: grey;
}

#supervisee-list, #employee-list {
    padding-left: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 580px) {
    .mark-super {
        position: static;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

I have tried messing around with different combinations of overflow: hidden and overflow: scroll on a number of different things, but nothing is helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've just tested your code and all I did was to remove the property "overflow" at all. It will remove your doubled scroll bar.
Also, becarefull using this:

```
#background {
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
```

While testing in two browsers it was giving me a browser scroll bar which was not necessary, I'd suggest you to use 100% instead.

Comment: what you said works, im just not super sure why tho